# How to get new coordinates of the edited shape and calculate the center dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, polygon, ng-map

I'm using `ngmap` in my application. I was able to display a polygon from its coordinates using `shape`. Now I want to make this polygon editable. I referenced this [link](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!user-editable-shapes.html) and my polygon is now editable. The problem is that I can't find how can I get the new coordinates.

Is there any events as `onMapOverlayCompleted` in the `drawing-manager`?

How can I get the new coordinates?

Also how can I calculate the value of the `center` attribute dynamically

Comment: Here is the same problem like yours, but using different method. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvbLr993/14/) if you want to try. You can draw anykind of shape and its dynamically. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the shape type, in case of `Rectangle` to determine the resized bounds you could utilize `bounds_changed` event. The following example demonstrates how to print the resized size of rectangle:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('DrawingManagerCtrl', function (NgMap) {
    var vm = this;
    
    NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
            vm.map = map;
    });

    

    vm.rectShapeResized = function (e) {
        var rect = vm.map.shapes[0]; //get the first instance of shape
        console.log(rect.getBounds().toString());  //print a new bounds
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm">
    <ng-map zoom="7" center="48.8588377,2.2775177" map-type-id="ROADMAP" street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
        
        <shape name="rectangle" 
          editable="true" on-bounds_changed="vm.rectShapeResized()" 
             bounds="[ [48.190, 2.649], [48.899, 3.443] ]">
          </shape>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942610/ngmap-cluster-change-markers-colors-after-zoom ?